# Persistent scheduling of ActiveMQ to disk leads to disk space growth

Tags: java, activemq-classic

The schedule of the ActiveMQ has undergone disk persistence, and over time, the `H:\activemq_data\test2\db-*.log` file continues to grow and will not be automatically deleted, causing our disk space to gradually fill up over time. And this `H:\activemq_data\test2\db-*.log` file cannot be manually deleted directly. How should we adjust so that these files can be automatically deleted and occupy less disk space? The following is the detailed configuration of our ActiveMQ:

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" schedulerSupport="true" schedulerDirectoryFile="H:\activemq_data\test2\scheduler" persistent="true" brokerName="test_activemq" dataDirectory="H:\activemq_data\test2\" useJmx="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">
```

We tried to directly delete these files a long time ago, but manually deleting them will cause the ActiveMQ to fail to start.

Comment: Hi, it seems you forgot to attach activemq config

Comment: This is my configuration:         
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" schedulerSupport="true" schedulerDirectoryFile="H:\activemq_data\test2\scheduler" persistent="true" brokerName="test_activemq" dataDirectory="H:\activemq_data\test2\" useJmx="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ? The db-*.log files are deleted once all messages have been removed. If you publish a lot of cron or repeating scheduled jobs, then there may be active jobs in each db-*.log file.

Comment: ActiveMQ version 5.15.0 ，Yes, I have released a large number of cron repetitive jobs. If the business status is not changed, is it impossible to reduce the files? Can this be improved only by reducing cron?